# Elegant way to get rid of comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the below templates:

One is used for unsigned and the other for signed.  Is there any elegant way to get rid of the compiler warning without suppressing it?

```
 warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
```

Would I need to write the function for each type, e.g. uint8, uint16 etc..?

```
template<typename X,typename Y,typename Z, typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<X>::value, bool>::type = true >
void debugValidateParameter( X aValueToCheck, Y aLowerLimit, Z aUpperLimit)
{
   if( (aValueToCheck > aUpperLimit) || (aValueToCheck < aLowerLimit) )
   {
    log("ERROR: ValidateParameters, aValueToCheck = % , aLowerLimit= % , aUpperLimit= %  \n", aValueToCheck, aLowerLimit, aUpperLimit );
    throw(std::out_of_range("Invalid Range"));
   }
}

template<typename X,typename Y,typename Z, typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<X>::value, bool>::type = true >
void debugValidateParameter( X aValueToCheck, Y aLowerLimit, Z aUpperLimit)
{
   if( (aValueToCheck > aUpperLimit) || (aValueToCheck < aLowerLimit) )
   {
    log("ERROR: ValidateParameters, aValueToCheck = % , aLowerLimit= % , aUpperLimit= %  \n", aValueToCheck, aLowerLimit, aUpperLimit );
    throw(std::out_of_range("Invalid Range"));
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have X, Y and Z? Shouldn't all values be of *one* type anyway?

Comment: comparing signed to unsigned is comparing apples to oranges.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me explain a bit what you got wrong here.

For me, it looks like you would normally want to use the same type for all three parameters. The most straight-forward solution would be this definition:

```
template<typename X>
void debugValidateParameter( X aValueToCheck, X aLowerLimit, X aUpperLimit)
{
   if( (aValueToCheck > aUpperLimit) || (aValueToCheck < aLowerLimit) )
   {
    log("ERROR: ValidateParameters, aValueToCheck = % , aLowerLimit= % , aUpperLimit= %  \n", aValueToCheck, aLowerLimit, aUpperLimit );
    throw(std::out_of_range("Invalid Range"));
   }
}
```

But if you then call that function with an unsigned variable and two literal integers, for example:

```
debugValidateParameter(someUnsignedInteger, 0, 100);
```

you would get an error since the type cannot be deduced -- for this, all parameters with type `X` need to be passed a value of the exact same type.
So deducing the type `X` is ambiguous and thus not possible. For me, it looks like you want to deduce the type based on the *first parameter* being passed (the "actual value") and simply try to *convert the bounds to that same type*. In other words, something which doesn't force you to write

```
debugValidateParameter(someUnsignedInteger, 0u, 100u);
```

This can be done by *disabling type deduction* for the second and third parameter, by specifying their type as `identity_t<X>` instead of just `X`, where `identity_t` is defined as

```
template<typename T>
struct identity { typedef T type; };

template<typename T>
using identity_t = typename identity<T>::type;
```

So your function definition then becomes

```
template<typename X>
void debugValidateParameter( X aValueToCheck, identity_t<X> aLowerLimit, identity_t<X> aUpperLimit)
{
   if( (aValueToCheck > aUpperLimit) || (aValueToCheck < aLowerLimit) )
   {
    log("ERROR: ValidateParameters, aValueToCheck = % , aLowerLimit= % , aUpperLimit= %  \n", aValueToCheck, aLowerLimit, aUpperLimit );
    throw(std::out_of_range("Invalid Range"));
   }
}
```

Here you can see the code in a [**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/T5z6b9).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need SFINAE or specialization, you just need that `X`, `Y`, `Z` have same sign. so you might use

```
template<typename T>
void debugValidateParameter(T aValueToCheck, T aLowerLimit, T aUpperLimit)
{
   if( (aValueToCheck > aUpperLimit) || (aValueToCheck < aLowerLimit) )
   {
    log("ERROR: ValidateParameters, aValueToCheck = % , aLowerLimit= % , aUpperLimit= %  \n",
        aValueToCheck, aLowerLimit, aUpperLimit);
    throw(std::out_of_range("Invalid Range"));
   }
}
```

but that requires that all arguments are deduced to the same type.

To avoid that, you may force some argument to be non deducible:

```
template <typename T> struct non_deducible { using type = T; };
template <typename T> using non_deducible_t = typename non_deducible<T>::type;

template<typename T>
void debugValidateParameter(T aValueToCheck,
                            non_deducible_t<T> aLowerLimit,
                            non_deducible_t<T> aUpperLimit)
{
   if( (aValueToCheck > aUpperLimit) || (aValueToCheck < aLowerLimit) )
   {
    log("ERROR: ValidateParameters, aValueToCheck = % , aLowerLimit= % , aUpperLimit= %  \n",
        aValueToCheck, aLowerLimit, aUpperLimit);
    throw(std::out_of_range("Invalid Range"));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
bool integral_less_than(T1 t1, T2 t2)
{
  static_assert(std::is_integral<T1>::value, "");
  static_assert(std::is_integral<T2>::value, "");
  // Handle different signedness.
  if (std::is_unsigned<T1>::value)
  {
    if (!std::is_unsigned<T2>::value)
      return (t2 < 0) ? false : t1 < static_cast<typename std::make_unsigned<T2>::type>(t2);
  }
  else
  {
    if (std::is_unsigned<T2>::value)
      return (t1 < 0) ? true : static_cast<typename std::make_unsigned<T1>::type>(t1) < t2;
  }
  // Handle same signedness.
  return t1 < t2;
}

template <typename X, typename Y, typename Z>
void ValidateParameter(X aValueToCheck, Y aLowerLimit, Z aUpperLimit)
{
  if (integral_less_than(aUpperLimit, aValueToCheck) ||
      integral_less_than(aValueToCheck, aLowerLimit))
  {
    std::cout
      << "ERROR: ValidateParameter():"
      << " aValueToCheck=" << aValueToCheck
      << ", aLowerLimit=" << aLowerLimit
      << ", aUpperLimit=" << aUpperLimit
      << "\n";
//    throw(std::out_of_range("Invalid Range"));
  }
}

int main()
{
  ValidateParameter(0, -1, 1);
  ValidateParameter(0u, -1, 1);
  ValidateParameter(0, -1, 1u);
  ValidateParameter(0u, -1, 1u);
  ValidateParameter(-1, -1, 1);
  ValidateParameter(-1, -1, 1u);
  ValidateParameter(1, -1, 1);
  ValidateParameter(1u, -1, 1);
  ValidateParameter(1, -1, 1u);
  ValidateParameter(1u, -1, 1u);
  ValidateParameter(-2, -1, 1);
  ValidateParameter(-2, -1, 1u);
  ValidateParameter(2, -1, 1);
  ValidateParameter(2u, -1, 1);
  ValidateParameter(2, -1, 1u);
  ValidateParameter(2u, -1, 1u);
  return 0;
}
```